# Load satellite assemblies from memory

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, satellite-assembly

Must satellite assemblies be present on disk in appropriately named sub-folders. Can they be loaded from memory, for example, via the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event?

I know assemblies can be loaded from memory, but will .Net use the AssemblyResolve event when looking for satellite assemblies.

Comment: Yes, you can load an assembly in run-time in dotnet.

Comment: I know assemblies can be loaded from memory, but my question is whether .Net will use the AssemblyResolve event when looking for satellite assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event, you are probably looking for a bunch of overloads for loading assemblies.. like so

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly)
```

Comment: I know assemblies can be loaded from memory, but my question is whether .Net will use the AssemblyResolve event when looking for satellite assemblies.